# Image referencing in css file - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: css, reference

If an image shows up in a div when I code:

```
background:url(/imgs/crowd1.jpg)
```

in the css, but is doesn't when I code

```
background:url(imgs/crowd1.jpg)
```

what does that indicate I am doing wrong?

Comment: The `/` at the beginning indicates that the filepath is starting at the root of the site, while the lack of a `/` indicates that the file path is relative to the CSS file's current location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/` means that it the file or folder is in the root folder while without the `/` means that the file or folder is in the current directory.

**Here is a brief description of other file paths:**

`./` means the current directory

`../` means the parent of the current directory, not the root directory

`/` is the root directory

`myfile.text` is in the current directory, as is `./myfile.text`

`../myfile.text` is one level above you and `/myfile.text` lives in your root directory.